# Can't access session using laravel 5.4 ajax call

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, session

Using laravel 5.1 this works fine on an ajax call:

```
$conn = Session::get('conn') or abort(500, 'No conn detected')
```

The variable is set and if the session key is not detected the error 500 is fired.

But on a brand new install of Laravel 5.4 the same code doesn't work, I can test it fine using a normal GET request but if I using ajax I always get the 500 error.  I'm using the 'file' session session driver in both cases.

Did something change from Laravel 5.1 to 5.4 about session access on ajax call? I couldn't find any info about it.

Thanks!

Comment: How did you fix this?

Answer (score 0):

In file `app/Http/Kernel.php` there is array `$middlewareGroups` and there `\Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class` is commented. Uncomment this line and try again.

Comment: Nop, what did work was adding: `\Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,` to the protected $middleware group, I don't know if that is the right way to go tho.